# Generalizing an incomplete Gamma function to many variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gamma-function, random-matrices

One of the topics of interest in random matrix theory is the joint distribution of eigenvalues of Gaussian random matrices in the Wishart ensemble, see

*Harnad, John (ed.)*, [**Random matrices, random processes and integrable systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-9514-8), CRM Series in Mathematical Physics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4419-9513-1/hbk; 978-1-4419-9514-8/ebook). xviii, 524 p. (2011). [ZBL1215.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1215.15002)., for example.

Now, in order to obtain the density of eigenvalues there is a need to integrate over simplices  with  the integrand being a product of power functions and an exponential. This leads to   a generalization of the Gamma function in $d $ dimensions  and as such motivates the following definition below.

---

Let $d \ge 2$ be an integer.  Let $\vec{n}:= (n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_{d-1}) \in {\mathbb N}_+^{d-1} $ where $n_j \ge 1 $ for $j=1,\cdots,d-1$. Finally let $\lambda_d \ge 0 $ be real.

###### Definition 1:

The multivariate lower, incomplete Gamma function  is defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
\gamma(\vec{n},\lambda_d) := \int\limits_{\Delta_{d-1}^{(-)}(\lambda_d)}
\left( \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1} \lambda_\xi^{n_\xi-1} \right) \cdot 
e^{-\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^d \lambda_\xi} \cdot \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1} d\lambda_\xi
\end{equation}

where $\Delta^{(-)}_{d-1} (\lambda) := \left\{ (\lambda_\xi)_{\xi=1}^{d-1} | 0 \le \lambda_1 \le \cdots \le \lambda_{d-1} \le \lambda\right\}$.

###### Result 1:

By using elementary integration and induction in the dimension $d$ and then differentiation with respect to parameters we have found the following formula below:

\begin{equation}
\gamma(\vec{n},\lambda_d) = (-1)^{|\vec{n}|-d+1}  \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1}  \frac{d^{n_\xi-1}}{d a_\xi^{n_\xi-1}} \left.\left(
\sum\limits_{j=1}^d (-1)^{d-j} \frac{e^{-(\sum\limits_{\xi=j}^d a_\xi) \cdot \lambda_d}}{\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{j-1} (a_\xi+\cdots+a_{j-1}) \cdot \prod\limits_{\xi=j}^{d-1}(a_j+\cdots+ a_\xi)}
\right)\right|_{(a_\xi)_{\xi=1}^d:>1} \tag{1a}
\end{equation}

###### Definition 2:

The multivariate upper, incomplete Gamma function  is defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(\vec{n},\lambda_d) := \int\limits_{\Delta_{d-1}^{(+)}(\lambda_d)}
\left( \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1} \lambda_\xi^{n_\xi-1} \right) \cdot 
e^{-\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^d \lambda_\xi} \cdot \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1} d\lambda_\xi
\end{equation}

where $\Delta^{(+)}_{d-1} (\lambda) := \left\{ (\lambda_\xi)_{\xi=1}^{d-1} | \lambda \le \lambda_1 \le \cdots \le \lambda_{d-1} \le \infty\right\}$.

###### Result 2:

Using the same technique as above  we have found the following formula below:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(\vec{n},\lambda_d) = (-1)^{|\vec{n}|-d+1} \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1}  \frac{d^{n_\xi-1}}{d a_\xi^{n_\xi-1}}
\left.
\left(
\frac{e^{-(\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^d a_\xi) \cdot \lambda_d}}{\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^{d-1} (a_\xi+\cdots+a_{d-1})}
\right)
\right|_{(a_\xi)_{\xi=1}^d:>1} \tag{2a}
\end{equation}

---

The Mathematica code snippet below  verifies the results above:

```
In[772]:= d = RandomInteger[{2, 6}];
L = RandomReal[{0, 5}];
n = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, d - 1];
(*Lower incomplete*)
NIntegrate[
 Product[l[xi]^(
   n[[xi]] - 1), {xi, 1, d - 1}] Exp[-Sum[l[xi], {xi, 1, d - 1}] - L],
  Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ 
   Table[{l[j], If[j == 1, 0, l[j - 1]], L}, {j, 1, d - 1}]]]
D[Sum[(-1)^(Total[n] - j - 1)/1 Exp[-Sum[a[eta], {eta, j, d}] L]/
    Product[Sum[a[eta], {eta, xi, j - 1}], {xi, 1, j - 1}] 1/
    Product[Sum[a[eta], {eta, j, xi}], {xi, j + 0, d - 1}], {j, 1, 
    d}], Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ Table[{a[xi], n[[xi]] - 1}, {xi, 1, d - 1}]]] /. 
 a[j_] :> 1

(*Upper incomplete*)
NIntegrate[
 Product[l[xi]^(
   n[[xi]] - 1), {xi, 1, d - 1}] Exp[-Sum[l[xi], {xi, 1, d - 1}] - L],
  Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ 
   Table[{l[j], If[j == 1, L, l[j - 1]], Infinity}, {j, 1, d - 1}]]]
(-1)^(Total[n] - d + 1)
   D[Exp[-Sum[a[eta], {eta, 1, d}] L]/1 1/
    Product[Sum[a[eta], {eta, xi, d - 1}], {xi, 1 + 0, d - 1}], 
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ Table[{a[xi], n[[xi]] - 1}, {xi, 1, d - 1}]]] /. 
 a[j_] :> 1
  
  

Out[775]= 0.0295689

Out[776]= 0.0295689

Out[777]= 0.00111378

Out[778]= 0.00111378
```

---

Now, having said all this the question would be twofold. Firstly, can we evaluate those derivatives in $(1a)$ and $(2a)$ in order to obtain some neat closed form expressions. Secondly, can we generalize those results to the case when the components of the vector $\vec{n}$  are real?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to the first question. Rather than computing those derivatives we used induction in the dimension to derive the following results below.
Let us denote by $|\vec{n}| := n_1+\cdots+n_{d-1}$ the $L^1$-norm of our vector in question.
Then we have:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(\vec{n}; \lambda) = e^{-d \cdot \lambda} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{|\vec{n}|-d+1} {\mathfrak A}^{(d-1)}_j(\vec{n}) \cdot \lambda^{|\vec{n}|-d+1-j} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

where the coefficients in the sum above satisfy the following recurrence relations:

\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak A}^{(d)}_j( \vec{n} ) = \sum\limits_{{\tilde j}=0}^j {\mathfrak A}^{(d-1)}_{\tilde j}(n_2,\cdots,n_d) \cdot (|\vec{n}| - d-{\tilde j})_{(j-{\tilde j})} \cdot \frac{1}{d^{1+j-{\tilde j}}} \tag{3a}
\end{equation}

for $j=0,\cdots,|\vec{n}|-d$ subject to ${\mathfrak A}^{(1)}_j(n) := (n-1)_{(j)}$.

---

Let us the following notation $n_{p,q} := n_p+ n_{p+1} + \cdots + n_q$. Then we have:

\begin{equation}
\gamma(\vec{n},\lambda) = \sum\limits_{p=0}^{d-1} e^{-p \cdot \lambda}  \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n_{d-p,d-1}-p} {\mathcal A}^{(d-1)}_{p,j} (\vec{n}) \cdot \lambda^{n_{d-p,d-1}-p-j} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
where  the coefficients in the sum satisfy the following recurrence relations:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathcal A}^{(d)}_{p,j}(\vec{n}) = \\
&&\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
-\sum\limits_{{\tilde j}=0}^j {\mathcal A}^{(d-1)}_{p-1,{\tilde j}} (n_1,\cdots, n_{d-2}) \cdot (n_{d-p+1,d}-p-{\tilde j})_{(j-{\tilde j})} \cdot \frac{1}{p^{1+j-{\tilde j}}} & \quad \mbox{if $\quad p\ge 1$} \\
\sum\limits_{{\tilde p}=1}^d \sum\limits_{{\tilde j}=0}^{n_{d-{\tilde p}+1,d-1}-{\tilde p}+1} {\mathcal A}^{(d-1)}_{{\tilde p}-1,{\tilde j}}(n_1,\cdots,n_{d-2}) \cdot (n_{d-{\tilde p}+1,d} - {\tilde p}-{\tilde j})! \cdot \frac{1}{p^{n_{d-{\tilde p}+1,d} - {\tilde p}-{\tilde j}+1}} & \quad \mbox{if $\quad p=0$}
\end{array} \tag{4a}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
for $p=0,\cdots,d$ and $j=0,\cdots,n_{d-p+1,d}-p$ subject to ${\mathcal A}^{(1)}_{p,j}(n):= (n-1)! \cdot 1_{p=0} - (n-1)_{(j)} \cdot 1_{p\ge 1}$.

---

The code below demonstrates how significant is the speed-up  when computing the quantity in question from $(3)$ rather than from its definition.

```
(*Definitions.*)


myComputeCoefficients[j_Integer, d_Integer, n_List] := 
  Module[{norm = Total[n], val}, 
   If[d == 1, val = Pochhammer[n[[1]] - 1 - j + 1, j]; Return[val];];
   val = Total[
     Table[myComputeCoefficients[jt, d - 1, Drop[n, 1]] Pochhammer[
        norm - d - jt - (j - jt) + 1, j - jt] 1/d^(1 + j - jt), {jt, 
       0, j}]];
   val];

myComputeCoefficients1[p_Integer, j_Integer, d_Integer, n_List] := 
  Module[{val, np = Total[n[[Range[d - p + 1, d - 1]]]]},
   If[d == 1, 
    val = If[
      p == 0, (n[[1]] - 1)!, -Pochhammer[n[[1]] - 1 - j + 1, j]]; 
    Return[val];];
   
   val = If[p == 0,
     Total[Flatten@Table[
        With[{npt = Total[n[[Range[d - pt + 1, d - 1]]]]}, 
         Table[+myComputeCoefficients1[pt - 1, jt, d - 1, 
             Drop[n, -1]] (npt + n[[d]] - pt - jt)! 1/pt^(
           npt + n[[d]] - pt - jt + 1), {jt, 0, npt - pt + 1}]]
        , {pt, 1, d}]],
     Total[
      Table[-myComputeCoefficients1[p - 1, jt, d - 1, 
          Drop[n, -1]] Binomial[np + n[[d]] - p - jt, 
         j - jt] (j - jt)! 1/p^(1 + j - jt), {jt, 0, 
        Min[np - p + 1, j]}]]
     ];
   
   val
   ];

d = RandomInteger[{2, 6}];
L = RandomReal[{0, 5}];
n = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, d - 1];
Print["d,n,L=", {d, n, L}];

(*Upper incomplete*)
{t1, res1} = 
  Timing[NIntegrate[
    Product[l[xi]^(n[[xi]] - 1), {xi, 1, 
       d - 1}] Exp[-Sum[l[xi], {xi, 1, d - 1}] - L], 
    Evaluate[
     Sequence @@ 
      Table[{l[j], If[j == 1, L, l[j - 1]], Infinity}, {j, 1, 
        d - 1}]]]];

{t2, res2} = 
  Timing[(-1)^(Total[n] - d + 1) D[
      Exp[-Sum[a[eta], {eta, 1, d}] L]/1 1/
        Product[Sum[a[eta], {eta, xi, d - 1}], {xi, 1 + 0, d - 1}], 
      Evaluate[
       Sequence @@ Table[{a[xi], n[[xi]] - 1}, {xi, 1, d - 1}]]] /. 
    a[j_] :> 1];


{t3, As} = 
  Timing[Table[
    myComputeCoefficients[j, d - 1, n], {j, 0, Total[n] - d + 1}]];
Print["The coefficients = ", As];

res3 = Exp[-d L] Sum[
    As[[1 + j]] L^(Total[n] - d + 1 - j), {j, 0, Total[n] - d + 1}];

{res1, res2, res3, {t1, t2, t3}}

(*Lower incomplete*)
{t1, res1} = 
  Timing[NIntegrate[
    Product[l[xi]^(n[[xi]] - 1), {xi, 1, 
       d - 1}] Exp[-Sum[l[xi], {xi, 1, d - 1}] - L], 
    Evaluate[
     Sequence @@ 
      Table[{l[j], If[j == 1, 0, l[j - 1]], L}, {j, 1, d - 1}]]]];


{t2, res2} = 
  Timing[D[Sum[(-1)^(Total[n] - j - 1)/
        1 Exp[-Sum[a[eta], {eta, j, d}] L]/
        Product[Sum[a[eta], {eta, xi, j - 1}], {xi, 1, j - 1}] 1/
        Product[Sum[a[eta], {eta, j, xi}], {xi, j + 0, d - 1}], {j, 1,
        d}], Evaluate[
      Sequence @@ Table[{a[xi], n[[xi]] - 1}, {xi, 1, d - 1}]]] /. 
    a[j_] :> 1];


{t3, As} = 
  Timing[Table[
    myComputeCoefficients1[p, j, d - 1, n], {p, 0, d - 1}, {j, 0, 
     Total[n[[Range[d - p, d - 1]]]] - p}]];
Print["The coefficients = ", As];

res3 = Sum[
   Exp[-(p + 1) L] As[[1 + p, 
      1 + j]] L^(Total[n[[Range[d - p, d - 1]]]] - p - j), {p, 0, 
    d - 1}, {j, 0, Total[n[[Range[d - p, d - 1]]]] - p}];

{res1, res2, res3, {t1, t2, t3}}
```

[image]