# Calculating the spectral density of random matrices from the Wishart ensemble.

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ d \in {\mathbb N}_+ $ and let $\vec{n} := (n_j)_{j=1}^d \in {\mathbb N}_+^d $. In addition to that let $x,y \in {\mathbb R}_+ $.

Let $ \Delta_+(x) := \left\{ (\lambda_j)_{j=1}^d | x \le \lambda_1 \le \cdots \le \lambda_d < \infty \right\} $ and $ \Delta_-(x) := \left\{ (\lambda_j)_{j=1}^d | 0 \le \lambda_1 \le \cdots \le \lambda_d \le x \right\} $.

Now we define two functions that are multivariate integrals over those two sets. Here we go:

\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma_y(\vec{n},x) &:=& \int\limits_{\Delta_+(x) } \left[\prod\limits_{j=1}^d \frac{\lambda_j^{n_j-1}}{\sqrt{1+ \lambda_j \cdot y}}\right] \cdot e^{-\sum\limits_{j=1}^d \lambda_j} \cdot \prod\limits_{j=1}^d d \lambda_j \\
\gamma_y(\vec{n},x) &:=& \int\limits_{\Delta_-(x) } \left[\prod\limits_{j=1}^d \frac{\lambda_j^{n_j-1}}{\sqrt{1+ \lambda_j \cdot y}}\right] \cdot e^{-\sum\limits_{j=1}^d \lambda_j} \cdot \prod\limits_{j=1}^d d \lambda_j \\
\end{eqnarray}

Those integrals appear when computing the spectral density of a square matrix from the [Wishart ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) under the assumption that the scale matrix ${\bf V}$ (see the Wikipedia page provided) is a symmetric matrix with one's on the diagonal and all the off-diagonal elements equal to each other . For details see

*Harnad, John (ed.)*, [**"An example with Σ≠cIp section 7.1.2 page 446 in: Random matrices, random processes and integrable systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-9514-8), CRM Series in Mathematical Physics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4419-9513-1/hbk; 978-1-4419-9514-8/ebook). xviii, 524 p. (2011). [ZBL1215.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1215.15002).

Now, by expanding the denominators of the integrand in a series in the variable $y$ , integrating term by term and then using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535321/generalizing-an-incomplete-gamma-function-to-many-variables/4535933#4535933) we found the following series expansion:

\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma_y(\vec{n},x) &=& e^{-d \cdot x} \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty y^m \binom{m+d-1}{d-1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{|\vec{n}|+m-d} {\mathfrak A}_j^{(d,m)}(\vec{n}) \cdot x^{|\vec{n}|+m-d-j} \tag{1a} \\
\gamma_y(\vec{n},x) &=&  \cdots  \tag{1b}
\end{eqnarray}

where the coefficients above satisfy the following recurrence relations:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak A}_j^{(d,m)} &=& (d-1) \sum\limits_{{\tilde j}=0}^j \sum\limits_{l_1=0}^m
\frac{m_{(l_1)}}{(m+d-1)_{(l_1+1)}} \binom{-1/2}{l_1} \cdot (|\vec{n}|+m-d-{\tilde j})_{(j-{\tilde j})} \cdot \frac{1}{d^{1+j-{\tilde j}}} {\mathfrak A}_{\tilde j}^{(d-1,m-l_1)}(n_2,\cdots,n_d)  \\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray}

for $m=0,1,2,\cdots$ and $j=0,\cdots,|\vec{n}|+m-d$ , subject to ${\mathfrak A}_j^{(1,m)} = (n-1+m)_{(j)} \binom{-1/2}{m} $.

We have checked numerically that for $d=3$ and $|y|<0.01$ the expansion in $(1a)$ converges pretty fast, i.e. truncating it at $m \le 10$ yields a precision of several decimal points.

```
GenerateCoefficients[j_Integer, m_Integer, d_Integer, n_List] := 
  Block[{norm = Total[n], vals},
   If[d == 1, 
    Return[Pochhammer[n[[1]] - 1 + m - j + 1, j] Binomial[-1/2, m]]];
   
   vals = (d - 1) Table[
      Pochhammer[m - l1 + 1, l1]/
       Pochhammer[m + d - 1 - (l1 + 1) + 1, l1 + 1] Binomial[-1/2, 
        l1] GenerateCoefficients[jt, m - l1, d - 1, 
        Drop[n, 1]] Pochhammer[norm + m - d - jt - (j - jt) + 1, 
        j - jt] 1/d^(1 + j - jt), {jt, 0, j}, {l1, 0, m}];
   Total[Flatten@vals]
   ];
d = 3; M = 10;
y = RandomReal[{0, 1/100}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
x = RandomReal[{1, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
n = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, d];
res1 = NIntegrate[
   Product[l[j]^(n[[j]] - 1)/Sqrt[
     1 + l[j] y], {j, 1, d}] Exp[-Sum[l[j], {j, 1, d}]], 
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{l[j], If[j == 1, x, l[j - 1]], Infinity}, {j, 1, d}]]];

norm = Total[n];
myCoeffs = 
  Table[GenerateCoefficients[j, m, d, n], {j, 0, norm + M - d}, {m, 0,
     M}];
myCoeffs0 = 
  Table[myComputeCoefficients[j, d, n], {j, 0, Total[n] - d}];

res2 = Exp[-(d) x] Accumulate@
    Table[y^m Binomial[m + d - 1, d - 1] Sum[
       myCoeffs[[1 + j, 1 + m]] x^(norm + m - d + 0 - j), {j, 0, 
        norm + m - d}], {m, 0, M}];
res2 // MatrixForm
res1
```

[image]

---

Now, my question is twofold. Firstly, how do we fill in the gaps in the post above, i.e. how do we find the result $(1b)$ and the corresponding recurrence relations.

The second question would be more generic. Is it possible to generalize those results to the case when the scale matrix ${\bf V}$ has a block structure with several blocks such that the elements in each block, elements that are off the main diagonal, are equal to each other?